# In Android, how to add a file to another application

Tags: android

I need to place a file inside of another application's specific folder. Is there a best practice, or related expected behavior for this?

To solve the issue, I have created the desired file during my APK's installation, then written its contents. While this works (since I have root rights), I want to know if is there a way to "request" another application to "create the file themself", this is mostly to guarantee that when that other application is removed, that it removes its files (since my app is the owner of that file).

I am unsure if this is considered good behavior, and could not "phrase" the question in a way that showed related results (I am not an native English speaker).

Comment: I dont think other applications provide access due to rights issue as their package is different. Data sharing is something else and writing data to some other application memory space is some different thing.

Comment: Can you give a specific scenario? It would make it easier to propose a solution.

Comment: @Kelevandos Basically, I want an HTML file placed within a HTTP Server application. At the same time, I need that file to be removed should the HTTP Server app to be un-installed, and be able to alter that file (or be able to erase/create it). Without using Root privileges if possible (but I do not believe it to be so).

Comment: Are you the developer of the Server app?

Comment: @Kelevandos Partially. The "server app" can be our product as well, but I cannot add that file (since the app has a different purpose), but I can add a "put_a_file_here_Intent"... at the same time, our users might want to use any other "server app", as long as it complies with the file instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to place a file, inside of another applications specific folder

If by "applications specific folder", you mean [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), this is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices.

> I want to know if is there a way to "request" another application to "create the file themselfs"

Not in general. Some developers might have an API for this in their apps.

Comment: I understand the security problem. This is mostly why I want to know if there is a "best practice" or "related expected behavior". So far I expect interaction with just one other app, so I can contact their developer and request an API or even send them the file myself and expect them to include it. However, should other apps do the same activity, then this would become a problem for me.

Comment: @Bonatti: "I can contact their developer and request an API or even send them the file myself and expect them to include it" -- I would hope that the developer declines, unless you provide a clear and good reason why they should be including your file in their app.

Comment: While I cannot give specific details, its basically this: We have a severely disabled group of persons (our users), that are not tech savvy, and that do not speak english. We are using a server tool to handle HTTP request/reply, and in that tool, we have a file that handles the request, listen for an input, then forward that input to our APP. In order to facilitate installation, we like to use the "Google Play" system, that presents the "install" button, and done. For our system to work, another APP would have to be installed as well, and the file placed in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

The official way of sharing data between apps is `ContentProvider`s.

There is no limit to what may back the specific provider - a file, database or some other data source. I think this is the best way to go in your situation.

The approach you have described is indeed strongly advised against. The whole Android security is based on the idea that you can't directly access the data of other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my proposal. I will assume that you can add functionality to the server app or define some technical guidelines for it at least, so that it's developers have to add the functionality.

A - Server App

B - Client App

1. [B] Create the html file in the common storage
2. [B] Save its location to some String variable
3. (Optional) [A] If there are more server apps that the user can choose from, make sure they all have a `BroadcastReceiver` with a common INTENT_ACTION.
4. [B] Send a broadcast `Intent` with the path saved in 2. as an extra value.
5. [A] Receive the `Intent`, check if the path in the extra is present.
6. [A] Get the file from the received path and copy it into the internal storage.
7. (Optional) [A] Add a `BroadcastReceiver` to monitor app uninstalls. When notified about the client app being uninstalled, remove the html file you received from it.

This is the basic algorithm, but I guess the implementation is obvious enough. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: What happens if the user decides to use any other HTTP server app? or even if they install two apps that use the same port? I ask this, basically, because I have root privileges and I can override whatever is installed, disable any package that conflicts with my application, and ask the user to install a desired/compliant HTTP server app, then writte a file as needed.... At the same time, what I expected would be a "best practices" related to inserting content to another application (and I am aware of the security flaws in this).

Comment: You can not insert content into other apps, this is against the basic security principles of Android. A good practice is to define the expected behavior (e.g. html stricture, Intent Action used) for other apps so that they can handle what you want them to do. Later, when the user wants to use such app, they will be given a choice by the system (based on the Intent Action). This is what happens for example when you try to open an url and the system asks which browser to use.